# How to get the sum of column in two different Layer attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How do I add the values of a column and then insert it in different table column? e.g. I have a 
layer1 with attributes as follow:
[image]

and layer2 with attributes:

[image]

I am trying to sum the MIN with the same ids at layer1 then insert the result in layer2.

Answer (score 2):

There is no GIS-specific aspect to your question, however, if you are using a database like PostGIS with your QGIS you can do the following: (I haven't actually checked if the syntax is correct):

```
WITH temp AS ( 
SELECT  the_branch, SUM(min)  as min_sum 
FROM layer1 
GROUP BY the_branch) 
UPDATE layer2
SET layer2.total_min=temp.min_sum
FROM temp
WHERE layer1.branch=temp.the_branch;
```

Comment: you could also use a virtual layer and a query (have not checked it either) like this.

Comment: @MrXsquared, good idea, haven't used it myself before though !